# How to fix: 'unitypurchasing' is already in use by another application?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, app-store

Various versions of an app have already been published to the Mac app store. The new version introduces in app purchasements. Now, when trying to delivering the app through ApplicationLoader, it fails with the following error message:

> ERROR ITMS-90511: "CFBundleIndetifier Collision. The Info.plist
>   CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.unity.purchasing.unitypurchasing' of
>   'SomeApp.app/Contents/Plugins/unitypurchasing.bundle' is already in
>   use by another application.

Do you have any ideas what causes this and how it can be fixed?

**Some additional background info:**

Before signing the package, all .meta files have been removed from the included libraries. A proper .entitlements file is in place. And signing is done by:

```
chmod -R a+xr "SomeApp.app"  
codesign -f --deep -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: SomeDev' --entitlements "SomeApp.entitlements" "SomeAppp.app/Contents/Plugins/unitypurchasing.bundle" 
codesign -f --deep -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: SomeDev' --entitlements "SomeApp.entitlements" "SomeApp.app"  
productbuild --component "SomeApp.app" /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: SomeDev" "SomeApp.pkg"
```

Any ideas what causes the issue and how to fix it are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Unity Editor**

1. Select Mac Platform and architecture set Intel 64 + Apple silicon
2. Check Create XCode Project
3. Project Settings > Player > Other Settings check Mac App Store
4. Validation under Mac App Store Options section
5. Build project

**XCode**

1. Signing and Capabilities - add App Sandbox and In-App Purcahse
2. Go to XCodeProject/AppName/Plugins/unitypurchasing.bundle/Contents/info.plist
3. Change Bundle identifier from **com.unity.purchasing.unitypurchasing** to **com.unity.purchasing.unitypurchasing.your.app** this ID must be unique across all of your apps
4. **IMPORTANT!** Now you need to remove signature from **unitypurchasing.bundle** by running this command in the terminal `codesign --remove-signature unitypurchasing.bundle`
5. Archive and Distribute App from the Organizer.

I hope this helps. I've finally updated all my apps and distributed a new one.

Answer (score 0):

1. When building a desktop Mac build, select Mac App Store Validation within Unity’s Mac Player settings.
2. Once you have built your App, update its info.plist file with your bundle identifier and version strings. Right click on the .app file and click Show Package Contents, locate the info.plist file and update the CFBundleIdentifier string to your application’s bundle identifier.
3. Sign, package, and install your application. Run the following commands from an OSX terminal, filling in “your.app” and “your.pkg” appropriately.
   **TIP:** To sign the bundle, you may first need to remove the Contents.meta file if it exists: your.app/Contents/Plugins/unitypurchasing.bundle/Contents.meta

```html
1. codesign -f --deep -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: " your.app/Contents/Plugins/unitypurchasing.bundle
2. codesign -f --deep -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: " your.app
3. productbuild --component your.app /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: " your.pkg
```

1. To install the package correctly, delete the unpackaged .app file before running the newly created package and installing it.
2. Launch the app from the Applications folder. The first time you do so, you are prompted to enter your iTunes account details, for which you can then make test purchases against the sandbox environment.

Checkout link for more Information:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPAppleConfiguration.html